# Preventing a C++ program from printing to std out, when called via python

Tags: python, c++, output

First of all, sending the output to NULL, as mentioned in other questions, does work for the output of the python wrapper but doesn't prevent the c-program itself.

---

Let's start with what is happening,

the goal is to write a python-program to solve specific math-problems.

This program uses SDPAp (SemiDefinite Programming Algorithm - Python) a python module which itself is nothing more than a wrapper for SDPA. SDPA is a solver for SDPs written in C++.

The SDPAp-module has an option to prevent some of the output being printed, but there is still some debris. This output comes from the SDPA itself and so far every attempt to prevent this has failed.

The python-program has to print the solutions to console, writing it to some file, etc. doesn't help the problem, since this program will be used as a subprogram later on.

---

### Structure

---

Python program - has to write in console

Python program - calls the SDPAp-module which is a python-interface for the SDPA which is a C++ program - writes to console

The C++ program shall not output anything.

---

Since this question is asked indirectly a reaction might take some while.

---

`sys.stdout = devnull` prevents python output, doesn't prevent SDPA output

Neither `subprocess` nor `os.system` is used.

Comment: What's wrong with passing `subprocess.DEVNULL` as the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments?

Comment: Its unclear whether you are executing a C++ program (perhaps `subprocess.call` or `os.system`) or whether you are calling a C extension library in python. These have very different solutions.

Comment: Question will be edited asap

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Are you sure it is writing to stdout? Maybe it is writing to stderr?

Comment: Also: Is SDPAp a wrapper that starts a separate process or is SDPAp a wrapper that loads a DLL or links against a lib?

Comment: Stderr was also send to null

Comment: I will try to understand what happens in the depth of sdpa.